# What relationship does the primality characteristic function have with the summation group that it's over? Can we form a sheaf?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, group-homomorphism, primorial

Let $G_n$ be the finite group of square-free integers that are divisors of $p_n\#$ under the law $x \star y := \dfrac{ x y}{\gcd(x,y)^2}$.  It obviously forms a boolean group.  Where $p_n\#$ is $p_2 p_3 \cdots p_n$.

Now take the map:

$$
\chi(s):= \sum_{g \in G_n} \mu(d)(g \mid s)
$$

where $(g \mid s) := 1$ if $g$ divides $s$ in the ring $\Bbb{Z}$; or otherwise $0$.  So you could write this as a sum over $g \mid s$ (typical number theory style) but we're not going to here.

Then $\chi(s)$ indicates on the interval $[p_n + 1, p_{n+1}^2 - 1]$ whether $s$ is a prime number.

I'm wondering if $\chi(s)$ has any relation to the group $G_n$?  Obviously it's a summation over $G_n$. Equivalently it indicates on the interval $[1, p_{n+1}^2 - 1]$ whether $s$ is a prime distinct from any $p_1, p_2, \dots, p_n$.

Thanks!

Not only does $\chi_n$ we'll call it indicate primality on $\pm [p_n + 1, \dots, p_{n+1}^2 - 1] := I_n$ but it also indicates the same on $\langle I_n\rangle^{\cdot}$ ie. the multiplicative monoid generated by numbers in that interval.  $1 \in M_n := \langle I_n\rangle^{\cdot}$ is included because it simply always evaluates to $1 =: p_0$ one of our "primes".  Just a note.

Next question is take $B = \{ \bigcap_{i\in I} M_{i} : I \subset \Bbb{N} \text{ is a finite set}\}$ i.e. the set of all finite intersections of these monoids as a basis for open sets.  Then clearly these sets at least generate a topology on $\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$.

So can we form a sheaf in which the $\chi_n$ is a restriction of $\chi_m$ for all $m \geq n$ for example on the interval $[p_m+1, p_{n+1}^2 -1]$.  And the same thing happens on the monoid side.  So I'm wondering if this topology where open sets are arbitrary unions of certain monoids is a good basis for some sort of sheaf!

---

**Attempt.**
Let $F:O(X)^{\text{op}} \to \textbf{CRing}$ be the commutative ring-valued sheaf on the open sets described in the question post.  So each open set $U \subset X$ is an arbitrary union of monoids generated by certain intervals.  The union of all these monoids clearly equals the whole space $X = \Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$ because their generating sets the intervals do, by definition.  Also the empty interval is in there by definition of finite union including $\varnothing$, etc.  So it really is a topology.  It's open sets are unions of the multiplicative monoids generated respectively by this list of $\pm$ intervals:

$\pm[2,3],\pm[3],\pm[3,7],\pm[4,7],\pm[4, 24], \dots$

The commutative ring:

$$
R = \{f:\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0 \to \Bbb{Z}\}
$$

And let $F:U \mapsto \{ f\vert_U : U \to \Bbb{Z}, f\in R\}$, then each $F(U)$ is a commmutative ring as well.

Then the usual indicator function of primality on $\Bbb{Z}\setminus 0$ or $\chi_{\Bbb{P}} \in F(X)$ is the unique map in the definition of sheaf such that restricted to $M_i$ it induces $\chi_i$.